# How do I insert a JSON response into a div?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

I have a `<div>` inside my view which I need to be updated with some information after a pressing a button. My function returns information in JSON, like this:

```
<%= button_to "Ping", {:action => :ping_server}, :method => :get, :remote => true  %>
```

The response in the browser is:

```
{"ping":"0.070004"}
```

How should I insert the value returned into my div, located at servers/server.show.html.erb?

```
<div id="pingDiv">

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking to bind to the `ajax:success` and `ajax:error` hooks. Check out "[Working with JavaScript in Rails](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#form-for)" for more details on how remote forms work.

```
$("#some_form_id").on("ajax:success", (e, data, status, xhr) ->
  $("#pingDiv").append xhr.responseText
).bind "ajax:error", (e, xhr, status, error) ->
  $("#pingDiv").append "<p>ERROR</p>"
```